# Strange Behavior with Wildcards and DIR Command in Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, dir

I've noticed when using DIR in windows command line for one particular case wildcards don't function as I'd expect. Example:

```
dir *.doc
```

runs *similar* to

```
dir *.doc*
```

I've only noticed this behavior when the wildcard directory precedes the period (which is an important and frequent case). Whats even stranger is if you run either:

```
dir *.d
dir *.do
```

It will execute as expected. It's only once you hit 3 character extensions the strange behavior starts. I mentioned it runs similar to the command above because if the contents after the *. is not the extension it will not return the file. E.g.:

```
dir *.tar
```

will **not** return file.tar.gz but **will** return file.targa

Why is this and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Raymond Chen of Microsoft covered this in quite some detail in a [blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx), which explains this parsing issue and where it originates.

Comment: @KenWhite - That blog post only applies to DOS. The wildcard rules are very different for Windows.

Comment: @dbenham: Read the article. Raymond specifically mentions that some of the parsing issues remain even under CMD.EXE's parser today. (Toward the end of the article.) As I said, it explains the issue and where it originates. I posted a comment and link, not  an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite - It is a useful article, in that it explains the derivation of some odd wildcard behavior. But it does not explain this particular issue. This problem is all about short file names. The article does mention long vs. 8.3 names, but it does not really give enough information to explain the behavior described in the question.

Comment: This is an updated link to the Old New Thing blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143

Answer (score 2):

The DIR command matches against both long and short names.

Windows file names that do not meet the old 8.3 DOS standard are automatically given a short file name alias that does meet the standard. (This can be disabled on NTFS drives)

For example, a file with a name of "file.targa" is assigned a short name of "file~1.tar" on my local hard drive. The rules for the short name are undocumented, and the assigned name varies depending on what names already exist within the folder when the file is created. But one thing that is consistent is that long extensions are truncated to the first three characters of the long extension.

Given that DIR searches both long and short names, you can now see that "*.tar" matches "file~1.tar" which is the short name for "file.targa"

This issue exists for pretty much every command that performs uses wild card file masks, including FOR, COPY, MOVE, REN, etc.

**Workarounds**

If your volume is NTFS, then you (or your administrator) can disable short names. But existing short names persist, it only disables generation of short names for future files. This is not a very practical solution, since you may not be in a position to know if any short file names exist.

If you simply need a list of files, without the other DIR info, then you can pipe the result of DIR /B through FINDSTR to get the desired result.

```
dir /b *.tar | findstr /le ".tar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension is the part after the last dot. Anything before the last dot is the filename, including dots as ordinary characters.

Also remember that dir matches short and long names.

Comment: Your last sentence is the key.